# ListView.CheckBoxes change column infrc

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListBox with Property:

```
this.artistsListView.Activation = System.Windows.Forms.ItemActivation.TwoClick;
this.artistsListView.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.artistsListView.CheckBoxes = true;
this.artistsListView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
this.check,
this.columnHeader1,
this.columnHeader2,
this.columnHeader4,
this.columnHeader5,
this.columnHeader3});
this.artistsListView.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
this.artistsListView.GridLines = true;
this.artistsListView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 73);
this.artistsListView.Name = "artistsListView";
this.artistsListView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(720, 144);
this.artistsListView.TabIndex = 9;
this.artistsListView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.artistsListView.FullRowSelect = true;
this.artistsListView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
```

But the checkboxes column index is the last.
How can I insert checkboxes column at first?

Comment: Instead, it should have appeared in the first column by default. Can you provide more code?

Comment: I edited the to full code.

Comment: Maybe try adding headers one by one instead of adding them all at the same time? It may be a bug with the ListView. E.g: `this.artistsListView.Columns.Add(this.columnHeader1);` etc.